# Why is cleartextTrafficPermitted tag not detected when enclosed in debug-overrides tag of my Xamarin Android network_security_config.xml file?

Tags: android, xamarin, cleartext

I have a Xamarin.Forms application, for which I am able to debug in cleartext (http) mode, based on the inclusion of a network_security_config.xml file as follows:

```
<network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

However, if I move the cleartextTrafficPermitted setting inside of a debug-overrides tag as follows, I get the error "Cleartext HTTP traffic to MYSITE is not permitted."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
      <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
  </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

My application is running in debug mode. Even though app debugging was already working and mode was Debug, just in case I tried adding debuggable:true explicitly to the application tag in my AndroidManifest.xml, and have also tried adding (Debuggable = true) as a parameter in the ApplicationAttribute over my main application class declaration, but regardless of how I set the app to be debuggable, the base-config tag seems to be ignored if it's nested inside of a debug-overrides tag. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other way to allow for HTTP to be permitted in debug mode but not in release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use domain specific config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <!-- default config that does not allow plain text traffic -->
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <!-- Specific config for local tests (enable plain text traffic) -->
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

The **debug-overrides** tag, as described in the android documentation, does not take the **cleartextTrafficPermitted** option.

[image: debug-overrides documentation]

Answer (score 0):

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

put this line in application tag in manifest file.

Comment: Thanks - while this answer didn't directly solve my issue, since putting this in the manifest file would not achieve my goal of having this set in debug mode only, it was helpful, because it made me realize that it was "UsesCleartextTraffic", not "Debuggable" that I needed to try setting in the Application attribute over my Application class. That does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the [Application] attribute over my Application class as follows allows me to use HTTP during debug compiles only:

```
#if(DEBUG)
    [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic=true)]
#else
    [Application]
#endif
```